# SSIS INCREMENTAL LOAD from excel source DATA

Tags: ssis

I am doing Incremental Loading which is taking much time because both my Source file and destination file are very large. Is there any solution that I can read Look up table data to be filtered based on source project_id (i.e Load into cache only the data which is having the project ids of Excel Source instead of all projects data)

Please advise.

Thanks
Sasi

Comment: For large data sets, I prefer no cache on lookup and make sure the key is indexed in destination (the lookup table). It is unlikely that you will hit the key more than once, right?

Comment: If you really want to do it the way you are proposing then use a conditional split on project_id and send each path through it's own lookup with the project_ID filtered. You can then Union all of your data back together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS incremental load FROM EXCEL SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51453238/ssis-incremental-load-from-excel-source)

Comment: Also, this isn't an incremental load. Incremental load process inserts, changes and deletes only. Excel typically isn't a source for an incremental load unless you are receiving an extract from someone